# Issues with "Recurly.js" form generation and GWT / AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt, recurly

I am building a user interface for Recurly account management in a GWT application.
This means there is no actual browser navigation happening between "pages" in the app, and client DOM state is maintained in memory until the user actually refreshes their browser.

In other words, when the user leaves the billing information "page" - the input elements still exist in memory and are simply detached from the visible area of the user interface.

Unfortunately, the fields that are being provided by "Recurly.js" are somewhat problematic here as they seem to be designed for use in a conventional framework where the user submits the form and then is redirected to a new page.

While they work perfectly for an initial submission of updated billing information (i.e. the first time the "form" is instantiated), if someone re-visits the screen multiple times without refreshing their browser, the fields do not accept input.

I have tried the following:

- clearing the inner HTML of the wrapping recurly div elements (into
  which the provided fields are drawn by Recurly.JS) and calling
  configure() again
- Not calling configure() after the first time it is called (in this case, subsequent visits to the page result in unresponsive inputs)

Is there a way I can tell Recurly.js to reset itself so that the provided fields can be redrawn? Or (and preferably) is there a way to configure recurly to use my own "input" fields for number, date, month, and cvv instead of those that are rendered into divs by Recurly.js?

Thank you

Edit:

I have discovered that Recurly.js is setting the visibility of their provided billing inputs to "visibility:hidden" after the form is accessed after being instantiated. If I can't force recurly to redraw the inputs, then I need to prevent this from happening some how...

Comment: Are you recreating the DOM nodes, or reusing them? Can you show us relevant code?

Comment: I am re-using the same DOM nodes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Recurly. A workaround could be to recreate the DOM nodes every time the form is displayed. I'm not entirely sure how your reuse-concept should work without weird side effects carrying over (as you're seeing). Otherwise, contact their dev team, they can probably help you.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion, will give that a try, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately creating and appending new nodes result in the same behavior as re-using the same ones. It seems Recurly.js does not know it needs to redraw them on subsequent calls to configure().

Comment: That's sounds a bit odd .. Here's another suggestion: throw it (and the recrly script) in an iframe and redraw the entire iframe. As you see the suggestions get consecutively worse :P

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a "readyState" variable in Recurly.js.
If I set that back to "0" before calling "reconfigure", the fields correctly reconfigure themselves.
This seems to fix my issue.

Comment: Just a note on this - this solution involved changing settings within Recurly.js and would require you to host that file yourselves instead of calling it from Recurly when the page loads.
The problem with that whenever Recurly updates recurly.js, you would have to update as well to stay synchronized with changes.

Comment: I didn't need to roll a custom .js to use this fix. `recurly.readyState = 0` before calling `recurly.configure()` worked for me.

Comment: You do not need to customize the javascript for this, the 'readyState' is just a variable.

Comment: As of Recurly 4.3.0 - setting `readyState = 0` before reinitializing causes initilization failure. Reinitialization is now supported by simply recalling configure.